# Check if a String is the current date

Tags: arrays, swift

I am new to swift and I would like to separate a string into an array. In my case the string is "20170227" and I would like to have it in an array like [2017,02,27]. I have tried doing this, but the code was way too long and I think by far to complicated for what it is.

```
 var date = "20170227"
 var Space: Character = " "
 let indexMain = date.index(date.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
 date.insert(Space, at: indexMain)
```

which eventually only returns 2017 0227, so I'm lost... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to create a date from a string OR just breakup a string into an array?

Comment: @SylvanDAsh I am trying to check if the date of the string is the same as the current date, so I am clueless about which one of both is best to use

Comment: Seems like this was asked an hour or two ago. Thanks for posting some code! Have you searched anyplace (particularly SO) for answers? What *specifically* are you looking to do - cast a String as a Date for comparing to the current date, or split one string into an array of three, or simply split a string into an array? Based on your answer to ASylvanDAsh, I'm thinking the first - in which case, your question is completely inaccurate from what you want. Please, consider editing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment if you want to check that date of string is current date than you can use `DateFormatter` to convert string to date and then use `isDateInToday` to check date is today date.

```
var dateString = "20170227"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString), Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date) {
     print("String date is today's date")
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @JohnDoodle Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get date components from given string

```
let dateString = "20170227"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYYMMDD"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)  
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .hour], from: date!)
```